# How to apply a nonlinear transformation to a specified region in an image using the Masking option

Tags: image-processing

I am attempting to apply nonlinear transformation to the bottom half of my image. I use the Masking option for ImageTransformation and use an array where the the only positive values are where I want the transformation applied. When the code is executed the transformation is applied to the bottom half of the image;however, the top half of my image is displayed as white. How do I make it such that the top half of the image remains the same? My code is below(where image is [image: image used in ImageTransformation]:

```
greyPineApple = ColorConvert[Reflected, "Grayscale"];
greyValues = ImageData[greyPineApple];
greyValues = greyValues[[All, All, 1]];
zeroFunction[x_] := 0*x;
greyValues[[All, All]] = 0;
greyValues[[367 ;; 700, 65 ;; 220]] = 1;
ImageTransformation[image, # + .02 Sin[20 # + 25] &, Masking -> greyValues]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `Masking` doesn't control where the the transform is applied, it just masks result image. However, you can control where the mask is applied within the transformation function.

In the below `#[[2]]` is the y-coordinate which (since `PlotRange` and `DataRange` are defaulted to `Automatic`) has values between 0 and *h/w* = `1/Divide @@ ImageDimensions[image]`. `427/790` is how far up from the bottom of the image to apply the transform.

```
ImageTransformation[image,
 If[#[[2]] < 427/790/(Divide @@ ImageDimensions[image])
   , # + .02 Sin[20 # + 25]
   , #] &
 , Padding -> "Fixed"
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way maybe help:

```
pic = ImagePartition[ImageCrop[image], Scaled[{1, 1/2}]];
ImagePad[ImageAssemble[MapAt[ImageTransformation[#, # + .02 Sin[20 # + 25] &,
Padding -> "Reflected"] &, pic, {2, 1}]], 10, White]
```